# How to reset std::cin when using it?

Tags: c++, std, cin

I have some problem with following code. I use it in Xcode (OS X).

```
for ( unsigned char i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            
    int value;

    std::cout << ">> Enter \"value\": ";
    std::cin >> value;
    
    if ( std::cin.fail() ) { std::cout << "Error: It's not integer value!\n"; } else { std::cout << "The value format is ok!\n"; }
    
    std::cout << "value = " << value << std::endl;
    
}
```

Here I just input 5 values in a loop. Everytime I check it on error. When I set the wrong value ("asdf") std::cin goes crazy and doesn't work anymore. See this:

```
>> Enter "value": 90
The value format is ok!
value = 90

>> Enter "value": 2343
The value format is ok!
value = 2343

>> Enter "value": 34
The value format is ok!
value = 34

>> Enter "value": asdf
Error: It's not integer value!
value = 0

>> Enter "value": Error: It's not integer value!
value = 0
80
32423
adf
3843
asdf
asdf
23423
```

How to input reset std::cin? I try to input another values but I can't because std::cin seems to not work anymore after my wrong value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use, when the condition, `std::cin.fail()` happens:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore();
```

And then continue with the loop, with a `continue;` statement. `std::cin.clear()` clears the error flags, and sets new ones, and `std::cin.ignore()` effectively ignores them (by extracting and discarding them).

Sources:

1. [`cin.ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)
2. [`cin.clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/)

Comment: `clear` clears the stream's error state flags. It doesn't do anything with the characters. And `ignore` without any arguments will only discard a single character, which means that if you enter `"asdf"`, it's going to loop through 4 times, telling you your input is bad before it lets you input again. You should do `std::cin::ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` to discard until the end of the line.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - I have a problem with "std::cin::ignore". I use CLang and it seems it should be std::cin.ignore but with only one param...

Comment: @JavaRunner: Yes, that is correct. I mistyped. But it should accept 2 arguments. The first one for the max number of characters, and the second one for a sentinel character. They are both defaulted.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out @BenjaminLindley I didn't realize. I was depending heavily on the docs, and didn't carefully read them. My bad