# Why this code cause an infinity loop when '|' is entered in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, cin

I was reading Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd Edition) 
 
I found this question:

- Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two
  ints and then prints them. Exit the program when a terminating '|' is entered.

Here is what I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
int x, y;
while (x != '|' || y != '|'){
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

When '|' is entered, it prints something like infinity loop,  unexpected outputs.

- What is happening there?
- What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your code reads "While x is not equal to '|' **or** y is not equal to '|'..." This means both variables have to be '|' in order for the loop to break.

Comment: Also, `x` and `y` are ints, not chars. They can't be '|'. Use `cin.peek()` to check for '|' before inputting them.

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour: you are attempting to use `x` and `y` without initializing them to anything.

Comment: @FeiXiang It says read two ints, using while-loop. not string sir.

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282953/how-to-reset-stdcin-when-using-it - you need to reset cin whenever there's an error (setting a non integer to an integer). also change your loop from "while" to "do-while", so that you do not have to initialise the starting value.

Comment: @DarinBenas For some reason, I did not think of `cin.peek()` at the time.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`. And consider using a `do..while` loop instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But sir, It doesn't exit the program when '|' is entered. I tried what you said.

Comment: @DarinBenas that is because you are reading `int` values and not `char` values, and are not doing any error handling on your `operator>>` calls. When `|` is entered, `cin >> ...` to an `int` variable fails.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to have no warnings. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand your program's behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you have not set `x` or `y` to anything before comparing them to `'|'` in the `while` loop. That means they may have *arbitrary* values and your loop may not even start.

---

As to *why* you're seeing an infinite loop, because the variables are of type `int`, the `cin >> something` will attempt to translate the characters that you enter *into* an integer and place it into the variable.

If the initial sequence of those characters do *not* form a valid integer (say, for example, it's the `|` character), the `cin >>` will fail, the variable will be unchanged, and the input stream will remain exactly where it is.

So, when you come around again to get the next integer, `|` is *still* in the input stream and exactly the same thing will happen again, ad infinitum - note the similarity between that Latin phrase and your question title :-)

---

What you can do to fix that is to *try* to look ahead character by character to see if you have a `|` in the stream. If so, just exit. If not, try to get two integers using the normal `if (stream >> variable)` method.

This can be done with `cin.peek()` to check the next character, and `cin.get()` to remove a character. You also have to take into account the fact that neither `peek` nor `get` will skip white space the way that `operator>>` may.

Something like this should be a good start:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    int x, y;

    while (true) {
        // Skip all white space to (hopefully) get to number or '|'.

        while (std::isspace(std::cin.peek())) std::cin.get();

        // If it's '|', just exit, your input is done.

        if (std::cin.peek() == '|') break;

        // Otherwise, try to get two integers, fail and stop if no good.

        if (! (std::cin >> x >> y)) {
            std::cout << "Invalid input, not two integers\n";
            break;
        }

        // Print the integers and carry on.

        std::cout << "You entered " << x << " and " << y << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Using various test data for that shows that it covers all the cases (taht I could think of):

```
pax$ ./myprog </dev/null
Invalid input, not two integers

pax$ echo hello | ./myprog
Invalid input, not two integers

pax$ echo 1 | ./myprog
Invalid input, not two integers

pax$ echo 1 2 | ./myprog
You entered 1 and 2
Invalid input, not two integers

pax$ printf '1 2|' | ./myprog
You entered 1 and 2

pax$ printf '1 2\n3 4\n5     6 7   8   \n|' | ./myprog
You entered 1 and 2
You entered 3 and 4
You entered 5 and 6
You entered 7 and 8

pax$ printf '1 10     11   12   13    14    |   ' | ./myprog
You entered 1 and 10
You entered 11 and 12
You entered 13 and 14
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what test data is. I'm beginner sir.

Comment: @DarinBenas, test data is, well, data you use to test your program :-) The section at the end shows various test cases (the input being given to the program by the `echo` and `printf` statements). You *could* just run the program and enter the values yourself but it's pretty much a given that automated testing is usually much more useful.

Answer (score 3):

As people have pointed out in the comments and in the answer by paxdiablo, you're two variables are uninitialized and you're trying to input into an int, and then compare it to a char.

Instead of trying to compare the inputted int to a char, we can use `cin.peek()` to peek at the next character and check if it is '|' before it is read.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    while(std::cin.peek() != '|') //cin.peek() will return the next character to be read
    {
        std::cin >> x >> y;
        std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
        std::cin.ignore(); //ignore whitespace/linebreak character left by extraction (>> operator)
    }
}
```

Comment: `cin` state should be checked. For non-int input, this is a infinite loop. BTW, not the downvoter....

Comment: Just for completeness, you may want to look at white space handling. The problem is that `peek` does not skip white space line `cin >> someInt` does, so entering `<space>|` will cause issues. Your answer (including the one-character `ignore`) seems to assume *no* superfluous white space. In addition, it's rarely a good idea to *not* check the result of `cin >>` to ensure it's worked (same as rchecking return value of `scanf` in C).

Comment: @paxdiablo I usually assume the input is formatted correctly in my example programs since otherwise, you would end up with some not really relevant code that confuses people. For example, the OP probably does not understand why `if(!(cin >> x))` checks if the input failed. For other programs, that might be code to check if the input is in range. That's just my opinion though.

Answer (score -1):

Because you defined x , y as integer but you are entering input as char.
try this code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    char x=NULL, y=NULL;
    while (x != '|' || y != '|')
    {
        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;
        cout << x << endl;
        cout << y << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but it has also limitation. you can only take input as single digit.if you want to take large number try this one

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string  x="", y="";
    while (x != "|" || y != "|")
    {
        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;
        cout << x << endl;
        cout << y << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```