# Find smallest element that has a minimum number of repetition

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

The program gets the size of an array and array elements as input. and the program is supposed to print the smallest element in this array that has a minimum number of repetition.

The size of the array is from **1** to **100**.

Number range is from **1** to **100**.

For example, if the input is **[1,2,1,3,4]**, the output must be **2**.

I tried to find out the number of repetitions for each array element, and then somehow connect it to the original problem but I couldn't find a way.

Thank you very much for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Please provide max number of elements and number ranges

Comment: @KamolHasan I edited the question and added the size of the array and its range.

Comment: So, where are you stuck? get the frequency count of each element and return the least frequency guy.

Comment: @v78 the problem is I also need to check if the minimum frequency is for the smallest number or not.

Comment: What kind of help do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
int main ()
{
  // array input 
  int ar[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6 };
  size_t n = sizeof (ar) / sizeof (ar[0]);

  // since maximun size of the array element is 100
  int occurrence[101];

  // set occurrence to zero 
  memset (occurrence, 0, sizeof occurrence);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      // count the occurrence of each number
      occurrence[ar[i]]++;
    }

  // let's set minValue to INT_MAX
  int minValue = INT_MAX, Value;

  // since the number range is 1 to 100
  for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
      // Update minValue and Value
      if (occurrence[i] != 0 and occurrence[i] < minValue)
        {
             minValue = occurrence[i];
            Value = i;
        }
    }

  // print the result 
  printf ("%d", Value);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: This is written in C, but the question is tagged c++.

Comment: It is not a very good idea to provide ready to use code. Question author might just copy and paste and would not learn anything... (@Eugene Maybe that would force QA to change the code a bit at least? Unfortunately, no C-features that wouldn't compile in C++ are used, so code still could be used 1:1 with a C++ compiler...)

Comment: @Aconcagua I traced the code and the algorithm of it and I learned a lot from it but yes I got your point.

Comment: One of your comments is wrong, though: Length of occurrences is not 101 because of maximu**m** size of array is 100, but because *values* are in range [1..100]...

Comment: @ArshiaR Well, at least you did... Many don't, if they get code. In the end, it's their own fault, but we actually didn't *really* help then. What I recommend to you now would be transforming the code into real c++ code (i. e. using std::vector for inputs, std::array for counting occurences. You might, just for learning, extend the algorithm for larger range of input values (hint: array might get too large then, so have a look at [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)).

Comment: @Aconcagua Got your points. I'm also new here. I'm learning gradually.

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for your recommendations. I converted the code to c++ and compiled it. I get the array size from the user and I made some changes to get it covered. I will try vectors too. thanks again, sir.

Comment: @n.m. didn't get you comment. I know you are disappointed. Can you mention the reason? So that I can improve myself in future.

Comment: @ArshiaR *'I converted the code to c++ and compiled it. I get the array size from the user and I made some changes to get it covered.'* Something like `std::cin >> n; int arr[n];`? Be aware that this is not valid C++! Variable length arrays (as this is called) are a feature of C (since C99, since C11 optional), but not part of C++. Some compilers support them as an *extension*, but code is not portable if using them.

Comment: @Aconcagua _italic_but not part of C++. Some compilers support them as an extension, but code is not portable if using them. good point. so I can declare the array with a fixed size and a for loop from 0 to N to fill it.

Comment: @ArshiaR Well, just as in given answer: Legal range of values is [1..100], so you need an array that can cover this range, so length must be 101 (such that `occurences[100]` remains valid). This array is independent of number of values to read in, you could read 1000 numbers, as long as all of these don't exceed range.

Comment: @ArshiaR If you want go one step further: Check user input! What would happen if user entered illegal values, let's say `x`? Stream state would get invalid and you'd only be reading 0 again and again, even if user doesn't enter any data at all any more. And if user enters invalid values, let's say `1210`? `if(!std::cin >> n) { /* error */ } else if(n < 1 || n > 100) { /* error*/ }` would cover both cases. Be aware that first case is more difficult to [recover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39282970/1312382) (have a look at second comment, though) from, so I placed them in separate if clauses.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the count of each element in a map. Then iterate the map and return the element with the smallest count. Using std::map ensures that the keys are stored in sorted order, which makes it easier to find the smallest element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter size of array: " << std::endl;
    int size;
    std::cin >> size;

    std::cout << "Enter the elements of array: " << std::endl;
    std::map<int, int> count;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        int num;
        std::cin >> num;
        count[num]++;
    }

    int candidate = 0;
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for (auto pair : count)
    {
        if (pair.second < max)
        {
            candidate = pair.first;
            max = pair.second;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Smallest element with least repititions: " << candidate << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

You need at least C++11 for the above code.

Comment: It is not a very good idea to provide ready to use code. Question author might just copy and paste and would not learn anything... Even worse than the other answer: You didn't provide any comments at all to explain your algorithm.

Comment: Nice approach. Since I am not very familiar with maps and the question was an exercise about arrays I preferred and array-based algorithm. But I will trace your algorithm when I started learning about more data structures such as map. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Aconcagua One of the principles of clean code is that it should be readable - so use good function names and variables. Comments should generally be kept to a minimum. The code itself should be understandable.

Comment: Not everything that is self-explanatory for experienced coders or professionals is so for beginners (like question author) as well. Iterating over your code again, need to admit, though, that in given case there's not really anything contained that might make even a beginner stumble... First point of criticism remains, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int N; //length of the array
int input_value; //input value to the array
int occurrence[101]; //number of occurrence of each array elements

int main (){

    cin >> N;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){ //input loop
        cin >> input_value; //get input
        occurrence [input_value] ++; //increase the occurrence of each value. Here the array value represents the index of 'occurrence' array
    }

    int minimum_occurrence_value = 100; //minimum occurrence cannot exceed 100
    int answer = 0; 

    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){ //maximum array element size is 100
        if (occurrence[i] == 0) continue; //avoid non-existence array elements
        if (occurrence[i] < minimum_occurrence_value){ //find minimum occurrence
            minimum_occurrence_value = occurrence[i];
            answer = i;
        }
    }

    cout << answer << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: It is not a very good idea to provide ready to use code. Question author might just copy and paste and would not learn anything... At least, you did comment your code, but you actually have an error in: range of numbers can be [1..100], but with `occurence` having length of 100, `occurrence[input_value]` is out of array bounds for input 100 (-> undefined behaviour)! So either increase the array by one or transform input values to range [0..99] by subtracting one (and adding one again for the final answer).

Comment: Very nice Explanation sir.

Comment: @Aconcagua thank you for the correction. I'm new to stackoverflow and highly appreciate your feedback on my answer. I will consider them when answering in future!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 100-element `std::vector<unsigned>` whose elements are initialized to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` (i.e., the maximum value an `unsigned` can hold). This vector is used to keep track of the number of occurrences of the different values. By taking advantage of the *wraparound* an `unsigned` undergoes after it is incremented by one when it has the value `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` (i.e., it goes from the maximum value to the minimum it can store, from `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` to zero), you can use the [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) algorithm to find the smallest element that has the minimum number of repetitions:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

int main() {
   int arr[] = {1, 2, 1, 3, 4}; 

   std::vector<unsigned> cnt(100, std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max());

   for (auto elem: arr)
      cnt[elem-1]++;

   auto pos_min_cnt = std::min_element(cnt.begin(), cnt.end());
   int value = std::distance(cnt.begin(), pos_min_cnt) + 1;
   std::cout << value << '\n'; 
}
```