# While condition: How to allow comparison between non-integer/double user input and integer limits

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, char, integer

Objective: Run a while loop that will repeat until the user inputs an integer between 1-3 (inclusive). So if an integer that is smaller than 1 or bigger than 3 is inputted or any character or string is inputted, the loop repeats.

My noob knowledge: I know how to compare user input when it is an integer, but when it is a char or string datatype input all I get is an infinite loop. Plus I declared the inputtable variable as an integer, so not sure how to go on about this.

I've done some Google searches but can't seem to find a question similar enough to mine.
Advice is highly appreciated :)

Code below:

```
int Decision1 = 4;

while ( Decision1 < 1 || Decision > 3)
      {
        std::cout << "Enter answer here: ";
        std::cin >> Decision1;
        std::cout << "\n\n";
      }
```

Comment: You have to check `std::cin` status and clear it in case of failure (and drop wrong character).

Comment: See [how-to-reset-stdcin-when-using-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282953/how-to-reset-stdcin-when-using-it).

Answer (score 0):

```
int Decision1;
while(std::cin >> Decision1) {
   if(Decision1 >= 1 && Decision1 <= 3) break;
   // todo
}
```

Comment: OP is asking for a while that loops until user enters valid input. In your code, if user enters invalid input `0` will be assigned to `Decision` and the loop is not entered

Answer (score -1):

You can use ASCII codes for checking number or character.

```
    #include <iostream>

int main() {
  char Decision1 = '0';

while (  (Decision1 < 49 && Decision1 >=47) ||  (Decision1 >51 && Decision1 <=57 ))
      {
        std::cout << "Enter answer here: ";
        std::cin >> Decision1;
        std::cout << Decision1;
        std::cout << "\n";
      }
}
```

I hope helpful for you.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to constrain this code to only ASCII machines.  Use character literals and the `<cctypes>` header instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, had a couple of questions.

In your while condition code:

```
while (  (Decision1 < 49 && Decision1 >=47) ||  (Decision1 >51 && Decision1 <=57 ))
```

Isn't that just going to compare it to 2 integer ranges? How does that differ from my while condition code that compares it to 1 integer range in terms of being able to repeat the loop only 1 time when a string or char input is entered?

Plus, since the Decision1 variable was declared as a "char", wouldn't a non-char input return an error?

Comment: You can return a error with a condition or you can use throw exception for return error.

Comment: Don't hardcode values for that range. Character codes for digits are required to be contiguous an increasing for **all** character encodings. So you can write `Decision1 >= '1' && Decision1 <= '3'`. That will work with **all** character encodings. I don't know what the second half of that `if` statement is trying to do, which demonstrates exactly why hardcoding values is a bad approach.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind: when you read input from `std::cin` you're reading **text** that's typed at the console. The stream extractor tries to **convert** that text to the target type. That is, in

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
```

the `>>` operator looks for digit characters and figures out what value those characters represent. If the characters can't be converted to an integer value the extraction fails. Streams have a conversion to `bool` that tells you whether the stream is in a good state, or whether an attempted operation failed. So:

```
int i;
if (std::cin >> i)
    std::cout << "got a value!\n";
```

To write a loop that prompts for valid input you need to reverse the test:

```
int i;
while (!(std::cin >> i) {
    std::cout << "bad input\n":
    // now clear the input stream, so it's back in a good state
}
```

To **also** check that the value is in the required range, just do it:

```
int i;
while (!(std::cin >> i) || i < 1 || i > 3) {
    std::cout << "bad input\n":
    // now clear the input stream, so it's back in a good state
}
```

To clear the input stream, you have to reset its internal flags. You do that with `std::cin.clear();`. And, depending on what you think was typed in, you probably want to get rid of any additional characters that the user typed. You do that with `std::cin::ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`. That tells the stream to discard character until it reaches a newline (press ENTER), or until it has read a huge number of characters.

Putting it all together:

```
int i;
while (!(std::cin >> i) || i < 1 || i > 3) {
    std::cout << "bad input\n":
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin::ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Yes, this clears the stream state and flushes the input when the input was a valid integer but out of range; that's harmless. It's a waste of time, but the speed of keyboard input is limited by how fast the user types, which is **much slower** than anything that the code in this loop does.