# Bad path not working how I think it should in C++ function

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I am taking a C++ programming course and working on a project. I am having an issue with the bad path of this problem. It is a user based input problem for temperature conversion. I have the happy path working great but the bad path is not acting like I expect it to. To my understanding, if I hit the bad path, it should wait for me to re-enter another input before exiting. In my code though, it just prints all the info in the bad path and exits.

```
#include "unitConversionHeader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <any>
using namespace std;

void tempOutputs(int, char);

void tempConversion() {
    // Parent function.Collect the inputs, handle the conversions and checks then return the result.
    int temperature;
    char units;
    char retry;
    char killswitch;
    bool running;

    running = true;

    cout << "This program converts Temperatures from Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa. \n";

    while (running) {
        cout << "Please enter your temperature: \n";
        cin >> temperature;

        cout << "\n";
        if (cin.fail()) {

            cout << "The value you have entered is incorrect or not supported. Would you like to try again? (Y/N): \n";
            cin >> retry;
            units = toupper(retry);

            if (units == 'Y') {
                break;

            }
            else {
                cout << "Too many incorrect attempts. Exiting program now. \n";
                cout << "Thank you. Goodbye. \n";
                running = false;



            }
            
        }

        else if (cin.good()) {
                cout << "Please enter your units (F/C): ";
                // convert to upper to eliminate risk of inputting the wrong value, lowercase is sufficient
                cin >> units;
                units = toupper(units);
                cout << "\n";

                if (units == 'F' || units == 'C') {
                    tempOutputs(temperature, units);
                    cout << "\n";
                    cout << " Do you want another conversion? (Y/N): \n";
                    cin >> killswitch;
                    killswitch = toupper(killswitch);
                }
                if (killswitch == 'N') {
                    cout << "Thank you. Goodbye. \n";
                    running = false;
                }

            }
        }


    }




    
void tempOutputs(int temperature, char units) {
    // After receiving the inputs we add the conversion logic and then run the calculations
    string lhs = "Celsius";
    string rhs = "Celsius";
    int calculation;

    if (units == 'F') {
        lhs = "Fahrenheit";

    }
    else {
        rhs = "Fahrenheit";
    }
    // taken from header
    calculation = unitConversion(temperature, units);

    cout << "A temperature of " << temperature << " degrees " << lhs << " is equivalent to " << calculation << " degrees " << rhs << ". \n";
}
```

When  I run the problem, if I enter a char for the first input and hit the cin.fail logic I just get the following output:

```
This program converts Temperatures from Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa. 
Please enter your temperature: 
f

The value you have entered is incorrect or not supported. Would you like to try again? (Y/N): 
Too many incorrect attempts. Exiting program now. 
Thank you. Goodbye.
```

What should happen is that it hangs and waits for me to enter another value to confirm how I would like to proceed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "bad path", my guess is "bad input". Your problem is improper retrying after a failed attempt. You need to be familiar with `cin::ignore` and `cin::clear`. There are many question and answers that successfully deal with this exact problem, please use the search function at the top of the page to find them.

Comment: An alternative approach that works very well is taking **all** user input using `std::getline`. If your program needs the input to be a number, convert the string you get to a number.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39282953/22081063) can answer  your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before these statements

```
        cout << "The value you have entered is incorrect or not supported. Would you like to try again? (Y/N): \n";
        cin >> retry;
        units = toupper(retry);
```

you should write

```
#include <limits>

//...

std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

to clear the input buffer. Otherwise the variable `retry`  reads the current content of the buffer that according to the provided by you output is the letter `f`..

Also it seems using the break statement

```
        cout << "The value you have entered is incorrect or not supported. Would you like to try again? (Y/N): \n";
        cin >> retry;
        units = toupper(retry);

        if (units == 'Y') {
            break;
```

contradicts the prompt.

Comment: Awesome, that did it thanks! Do you have any idea why that happens? Shouldn't it just clear by default?

Comment: @Asutherland8219 If a data can not be read from the input buffer it stays in the buffer.